# Overlap Status Bar With All Views

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm making a custom gradient tool bar in Xamarin.Forms and I would like it to start showing **under the status bar** in the android version.
I tried using the **first color** in the gradient colors as the status bar color but it was **too big** to feel gradient.
I also tried making the window full screen but it removed all the status icon that I need to view as well

[image]

above is how I would like it to look like

Answer (score 1):

In order to put a custom gradient toolbar under the status bar in Android, you will have to Hide the `NavigationBar`, that can be achieved in xaml by:

`NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`

Or in the code-behind:

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`